# Get url directed/from with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

How can I find the URL being directed from (ie the page the user is on before controller executes)?

Comment: You could try `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but that's unreliable at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `$this->input->server('HTTP_REFERER');`

[source](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)